# Open and close cursor in function and asyncronous call issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have written a postgresql function in 2 ways. Actually I have converted it from Oracle. It works fine. But I have some confusion written in last part. Please check the function and give me suggestions. Thanks for your patience.

**Postgresql version: 9.2**

### Option#1:

```
-- Function: to_tdfkcd(character varying)

-- DROP FUNCTION to_tdfkcd(character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_tdfkcd(i_tdfkname character varying)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    CUR_TDFK CURSOR (V_TDFKNAME character varying) FOR SELECT TDFKCD FROM TM_TDFK WHERE TDFKNAME = TRIM(V_TDFKNAME);
    V_RETURN TM_TDFK.TDFKCD%TYPE;
BEGIN
    V_RETURN := NULL;
    FOR CUR_TDFK_DT IN CUR_TDFK (I_TDFKNAME ) LOOP
        IF CUR_TDFK_DT.TDFKCD IS NULL OR CUR_TDFK_DT.TDFKCD = ''
        THEN
            RETURN V_RETURN;
        ELSE
            RETURN CUR_TDFK_DT.TDFKCD;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;  
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

### Checking Function Result for Option#1:

> ```
> SELECT TO_TDFKCD('国外');
>
> Output:
>
> 99
> ```

### Option#2:

```
-- Function: to_tdfkcd(character varying)

-- DROP FUNCTION to_tdfkcd(character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_tdfkcd(i_tdfkname character varying)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
 V_RETURN character varying DEFAULT '';
 CUR_TDFK_DT RECORD;
 CUR_TDFK CURSOR (V_TDFKNAME character varying)
 FOR SELECT TDFKCD 
 FROM TM_TDFK
 WHERE TDFKNAME = TRIM(V_TDFKNAME);
BEGIN
   -- Open the cursor
   OPEN CUR_TDFK(I_TDFKNAME);

   LOOP
    -- fetch row into the table
      FETCH CUR_TDFK INTO CUR_TDFK_DT;
    -- exit when no more row to fetch
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

    -- build the output
      IF CUR_TDFK_DT.TDFKCD IS NULL OR CUR_TDFK_DT.TDFKCD = ''
      THEN
        V_RETURN := NULL;
      ELSE
        V_RETURN := CUR_TDFK_DT.TDFKCD;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   -- Close the cursor
   CLOSE CUR_TDFK;

   RETURN V_RETURN;
END; $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

### Checking Function Result for Option#2:

> ```
> SELECT TO_TDFKCD('国外');
>
> Output:
>
> 99
> ```

I have some queries.

1. Which one I should prefer? `Option#1` or `Option#2`.
2. Is there any complexity?
3. In `Option#2`, is **OPEN** and **CLOSE** cursor can make any problem for
   multi-threaded environment or concurrently called from my web application?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you simply return the result of `SELECT TDFKCD FROM TM_TDFK WHERE TDFKNAME = TRIM(V_TDFKNAME) and TDFKCD IS NULL OR TDFKCD = ''` I don't see the need for a cursor (or even PL/pgSQL) at all

Comment: Option#3: `create or replace function to_tdfkcd(i_tdfkname varchar) returns varchar as $body$ select tdfkcd from tm_tdfk where tdfkname = trim(i_tdfkname) $body$ immutable language sql;` [Query Language (SQL) Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-sql.html)

Comment: Actually my client asked to convert the function. Would you please clarify my questions? Thanks for response. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @Abelisto It not works. It gives error `ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return character varying`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sir, Would you please clarify my 3rd query `In Option#2, is OPEN and CLOSE cursor can make any problem for multi-threaded environment or concurrently called from my web application?`

Comment: Both functions seem to be nonsense. I am almost certain that you don't need an explicit cursor (probably no looping at all), but you did not clarify what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter It was client's requirement to porting the function oracle to postgre. I know I can easily do it by this query `SELECT TDFKCD FROM TM_TDFK WHERE TDFKNAME = TRIM(V_TDFKNAME) and TDFKCD IS NOT NULL and TDFKCD != ''`. But I actually want to know my 3rd query `In Option#2, is OPEN and CLOSE cursor can make any problem for multi-threaded environment or concurrently called from my web application?`. Would you please clarify me? Thanks for comment.